# Is using Hibernate's Restrictions.eq() method safe against SQL injection?

Tags: hibernate, sql-injection, hibernate-criteria, hibernate-restrictions

Is using Hibernate's Restrictions.eq() method, as used in the example below, safe against SQL injection? Or similar methods like Restrictions.in(), Restrictions.ge(), ...

```
String vulnerable = //parameter from user interface 
Criteria ct = this.getCriteria();
ct.add(Restrictions.eq("propertyName", vulnerable));
```

I have found that probably is, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065906/does-hibernate-criteria-api-completely-protect-from-sql-injection?rq=3)

but reviewing [OWASP documentation](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Query_Parameterization_Cheat_Sheet.html#using-java-with-hibernate), there is an example that shows a comment which confuses me (`// This should REALLY be validated too`). Is needed to validate the input, or is secure as is?

The example in the OWASP documentation

```
// Criteria API
// This should REALLY be validated too
String userSuppliedParameter = request.getParameter("Product-Description");
// Perform input validation to detect attacks
Inventory inv = (Inventory) session.createCriteria(Inventory.class).add
(Restrictions.eq("productDescription", userSuppliedParameter)).uniqueResult();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Hibernate's Criteria API would protect you against SQL Injection, as it parameterises the query - you can see this in action by enabling sql logging.

What you do need to be careful about is concatenating user inputs etc. I think the documentation may perhaps be referring to validate the user input at both client and server side.